Implementing paraxial ray tracing using 3D vectors
Given a 3D ray tracer where rays are defined with a position vector and direction vector, we can formulate real (exact) ray tracing as the following two operations:

Find the ray intersection with a surface
Use the vector form of Snell's law to adjust the ray direction upon refraction or reflection

I am wondering how to adjust this work flow to accommodate paraxial ray tracing. Especially for tracing rays with large angles in a paraxial manner to compare their ideal performance.
In paraxial ray tracing, as I understand it, it has two steps:

Find the ray intersection with a planar surface (all surfaces are approximated as planar and the curvature of the surface is instead used for the refraction calculation below)
Use the paraxial refraction equation in 2D shown below

$$n'\tan{U'}=n\tan{U}-yC(n'-n)$$
where $n$ and $n'$ are the indices of refraction, $U$ and $U'$ are the angles of the ray with the optical axis, $C$ is the curvature of the surface and $y$ is the height the ray intersects a surface.
I am wondering if the refraction equation above can be written in vector format that fits the 3D real ray tracing I mentioned above. Or is there a different way to implement 3D paraxial ray tracing?
Thank you
